# MongoDB does not refresh data automatically?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I use **MEAN** stack for developing. And after adding some data to MongoDB, the new data is available in front-end only after restarting NodeJS server. There is any way to update MongoDB data 'online'?

This is my API (Node.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vt');

var Video = mongoose.Schema({
    idv: String,
    thumbnail: Number,
    aud : String,
    title : String,
    description : String
});
var db;
var video = mongoose.model('video',Video);
video.find({}, function (err, data) {
    db = data;
});

router.get('/api/videos', function (req, res) {
    res.send(db);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am adding data via Mongo Shell, it looks like this: `db.videos.insert({'idv': '8ifJvMlITNc'})`. After that, I get all data from `videos` table via Ajax. There is no new data in the response from the server until I restart Node.js server

Comment: Can you post some code here? How are you `adding` data here? How are you showing data in frontend? Is it via rest API?

Comment: @SarasArya I am adding data via Mongo Shell, it looks like this: 
`db.videos.insert({'idv': '8ifJvMlITNc'})`. After that i get all data from `videos` table via ajax. There is no new data in respond from the server until i restart NodeJS server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Node.js app you are fetching the data only once. You are not fetching it when request is received. Change the code to following and you don't have to restart for reading data:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var router = express.Router();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vt');

var Video = mongoose.Schema({
    idv: String,
    thumbnail: Number,
    aud : String,
    title : String,
    description : String
});

var video = mongoose.model('video',Video);

router.get('/api/videos', function (req, res) {
    video.findOne({}, function (err, data) {
        if (err || !data) {
            res.status(500).send();
        }

        res.status(200).send(data);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Please accept as correct answer & upvote if you found it helpful. Thanks!