# Mongoose not fetching data until I refresh the database connection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, redux, axios

I am trying to re-fetch the data from MongoDB using mongoose whenever a user reloads the page. However, the old data stays there and the new data doesn't get fetched until I restart the server.

Here is the router:

```
router.post("/dashboard", (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.body.userId;
  User.findOne({ _id: userId }, (err, users) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send();
    } else {
      router.get("/dashboard", (req, res, next) => {
        const leagues = [users.leagues.premium, users.leagues.free];
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.status(200).send(leagues);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

And here is the Actions (Redux):

```
export const fetchLeagues = userId => dispatch => {
  axios.post("/api/leagues/dashboard", userId).then(
    setTimeout(function() {
      axios.get("/api/leagues/dashboard").then(leagues => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_LEAGUES,
          payload: leagues
        });
      });
    }, 50)
  );
};
```

The data must be fetched from a specific user, so that's why I am posting the user Id,  then getting the data back. Not sure if this is the best way of doing this.

Just to clarify, I am using the MERN stack with redux and axios to execute this. I tried to use this: [MongoDB does not refresh data automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41660638/mongodb-does-not-refresh-data-automatically), but I still can't get this thing to refresh/re-fetch the data when the router is called again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a POST request then a GET request seems unnecessary here as you can just return the data in a single request.

The reason why the data is being persisted is because when you declare the `router.get('/dashboard')` route you are permanently hardcoding that route to have the values from the first request.

It's probably best to use a `GET` request, as that is what you are trying to do.

e.g.

```
router.get("/dashboard/:userId", (req, res) => {
  const userId = req.params.userId;
  User.findOne({ _id: userId }, (err, users) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send();
    } else {
      const leagues = [users.leagues.premium, users.leagues.free];
      if (err) return next(err);
      res.status(200).send(leagues);
    }
  });
});
```

```
// Where userId is now a string
export const fetchLeagues = userId => dispatch => {
  axios.get(`/api/leagues/dashboard/${userId}`).then(leagues => {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_LEAGUES,
      payload: leagues
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Though I was getting a 404 error, but after I changed 2 things it worked for me!
2 things I changed: 
From 
       axios.post(`/api/leagues/dashboard/${userId}`) 
to 
           axios.post(`/api/leagues/dashboard/${userId.userId}`)
and From router.get() To router.post()
Thank you again!

Comment: I just realized the 1st error was because I was returning userId as an object so that wasn't on you. Sorry

Comment: Glad you got it working! I changed my answer to use `axios.get` instead of `axios.post` because as far as I can tell there is no reason to use a post request, but both will work.